# Configure a user to access Parse Dashboard remotely

Tags: docker, parse-platform, parse-server

Here's what I get trying to access the parse-dashboard running on Docker (local)

[image]

Here's the docker command I run:

```
docker run -d -p 4040:4040 --name myappname-local-dashboard -e PARSE_DASHBOARD_ALLOW_INSECURE_HTTP=1 -e USER1=admin  -e USER1_PASSWORD=pass -v /home/xybrek/parse-dashboard/config.json:/home/xybrek/parse-dashboard/Parse-Dashboard/parse-dashboard-config.json parse-dashboard
```

**config.json**

```
{  
    "appId": "appId",
    "cloud": "main.js",
    "masterKey": "masterKey",
    "javascriptKey" : "javascriptKey",
    "restAPIKey" : "restAPIKey",
    "databaseURI": "mongodb://localhost/test",
    "port": 8080
}
```

**parse-dashboard-config.json**

```
{
  "apps": [{
    "serverURL": "http://localhost:1337/parse",
    "appId": "appId",
    "masterKey": "masterKey",
    "appName": "myappname",
    "iconName": ""
  }],
  "iconsFolder": "icons",
  "users": 
  [
    {
        "user":"admin",
        "pass":"pass"
    }
  ]
}
```

What could be wrong here?

Comment: Which IP are you referring to?

Comment: serverURL: http://localhost:1337/parse

Comment: Hello I can access parse  'http://localhost:1337/parse'  using the browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're placing the config in a wrong place.

Use this:

```
docker run -d -p 4040:4040 --name myappname-local-dashboard \
-e PARSE_DASHBOARD_ALLOW_INSECURE_HTTP=1 \
-e USER1=admin  \
-e USER1_PASSWORD=pass \
-v $(pwd)/parse-dashboard-config.json:/src/Parse-Dashboard/parse-dashboard-config.json \
parse-dashboard
```

Also I changed the source of the volume (`$(pwd)/parse-dashboard-config.json`) to get the config from your current dir.

See [docs](https://github.com/parse-community/parse-dashboard#run-with-docker).

---

Edit. Maybe you need to add `apps` to user config:

```
{
  "apps": [{
    "serverURL": "http://localhost:1337/parse",
    "appId": "appId",
    "masterKey": "masterKey",
    "appName": "myappname",
    "iconName": ""
  }],
  "iconsFolder": "icons",
  "users": 
  [
    {
        "user":"admin",
        "pass":"pass",
        "apps": [{"appId": "appId"}]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: > parse-dashboard@1.0.25 dashboard /src
> node ./Parse-Dashboard/index.js & webpack --config webpack/build.config.js --progress --watch
2017-05-23T19:13:40.948297656Z 
There was a problem loading the dashboard. Exiting. [TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined]

Comment: why is it needed to have "$(pwd)/parse-dashboard-config.json" and also have another config "/src/Parse-Dashboard/parse-dashboard-config.json"

Comment: The '$(pwd)' is only to not hardcode a path. Second, `/src/Parse-Dashboard/` it is not another config. It's where the config to be expected by the application. You mount a volume in docker as this: `docker run -v <local_path>:<container_path>`

Comment: I still get "Configure a user to access Parse Dashboard remotely"

Comment: I tried it and worked fine. But I used the example config file: https://github.com/parse-community/parse-dashboard#separating-app-access-based-on-user-identity